# Convert C# string to C++ WCHAR* over COM

Tags: c#, c++, string, com, interop

I have a COM local server (implemented in C++) which I am trying to call from C# code. The method that's giving me trouble looks like this:

```c++
HRESULT Foo([in] const WCHAR* bar);
```

The parameter shows up in on the C# side as a `ref ushort`, but I want to pass a string to the method, not a number. How can I make this method accept a string from C#?

The C# is pretty simple:

```c#
IFooService service = new IFooService();
service.Foo("blah blah");
```

I see other answers which describe `DllImport`ing the function and then using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` on the parameter, but since the COM server is running as a local server (meaning it's a standalone exe instead of a dll), and it's part of an interface, I don't think I can `DllImport` it. Do I need to do something with the server's proxy dll instead?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? E.g. do you have access to `dynamic`?

Comment: 4, so I do have access to `dynamic`. When I pass a dynamic string to the method, I get: `An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Foo'` I'm guessing that is because there isn't a version of the method which takes a string.

Comment: On what object are you trying to call the `Foo` method? Could you please post the actual method call.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, I added the method call to the question.

Comment: Is there a chance you can change the COM server?

Comment: @sharptooth, yes, I can change the COM server.

Comment: Good, then you'll be much better off using `BSTR` in the interface. Easier to marshall overall and C# will pass `String` there without any effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are at least two solutions to this problem.

1. Add the [string attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367270.aspx) to the parameter in the IDL to treat the pointer as a string, so this:

   ```
   HRESULT Foo([in] const WCHAR* bar);
   ```

   becomes this:

   ```
   HRESULT Foo([in, string] const WCHAR* bar);
   ```

   Then, a string can be passed to the method from C#.
2. Follow the instructions at http://www.moserware.com/2009/04/using-obscure-windows-com-apis-in-net.html and use the aptly-named `ComImport` attribute to declare the interface and prefix the string parameters with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`.

I went with #1 since it is the simplest and doesn't involve adding a bunch of extra code to to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
dynamic bar = "blah blah blah";
IFooService service = new IFooService();
service.Foo(bar);
```

Comment: Same issue, the client connects to the COM server fine, but I get `An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Foo'` in "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly".

Comment: I'm assuming `object` in this case is an instance `IFooService`. Are you sure it has a `Foo` method and that that method is an instance method?

Comment: It's over my head :-).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I learned about dynamic types today! :)